# How to use an .mdw file in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, mdw

In Access 2010, how do you open a database (created in Access 2003) which requires an .mdw file to be used? In Access 2003 you had to reference the .mdw file first.  I can't find out how you would do that in Access 2010.

Can someone tell me how to open the .mdb file in Access 2010?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To open an Access database that has user-level security enabled and does not use the system default Workgroup (`.mdw`) file you need to launch Access with [command-line arguments](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209207) that specify the database to be opened and the Workgroup (`.mdw`) file to be used. This is usually done with a Windows shortcut whose `Target:` is something like...

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\__tmp\zzzzz.mdb" /WRKGRP "C:\__tmp\Security.mdw"
```

...although the same thing can be accomplished from a batch file or similar "launcher" app.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I've only ever had to do this through the MSACCESS menu options.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a command line to access your `.mdb` using your original workgroup file, I actually go to the folder where the new workgroup file is, and replace it with my own. The path to the new workgroup file is: `C:\users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Access`. Inside this folder, there are 3 `.mdw` files and I found out that `system3.mdw` is running when I open Access 2010. As such, I replace this file with my own workgroup file (of course, you should make a copy of the original `system3.mdw` before you replace it with your own). Now when I run my `.mdb`, the username/password dialog box will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Target is ok Without the quotes (") for the .mdw and .mdb  file : as

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" C:__tmp\zzzzz.mdb /WRKGRP C:__tmp\Security.mdw

Answer (score 0):

Joining a workgroup is still possible in later version.
From the Debug Window, simply run:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWorkgroupAdministrator`
```

and browse for your mdw file.