# How to modify a security mdw file in access 2013?

Tags: security, ms-access, mdw

I am quite new to ms access.I have an mdb legacy file along with its mdw file. when I open the mdw file I can only see some queries not the underlying tables. I searched through web to find a solution but not a useful info I could find. How can I see them as well
and modify them? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119986/how-to-use-an-mdw-file-in-access-2010

Comment: Thanks @Thinkingcap But it is not what im looking for. I already open the mdb using this technique. I need a way to modify users and groups in the mdw file.